# Physics question on 1D motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

could someone please help me solve this problem? I can't seem to get the right answer :(

A ball thrown up from a rooftop of height 40 m lands on the ground in 4.8 s.

a) What is the maximum height above the ground?

b) What is its speed  25 m below the rooftop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ignore the horizontal motion.

$y(t)=40+v_{initial} t-\frac{1}{2} g t^2 $

$y'(t)= v_{initial} - gt$

A ball thrown up from a rooftop of height 40 m lands on the ground in 4.8 s.

$0=40+v_{initial} (4.8) -\frac{1}{2} g (4.8)^2 $

$v_{initial} = \frac{-40+\frac{1}{2} g (4.8)^2}{4.8} =(-40+ (.5)(9.8) (4.8)^2) / 4.8 \approx 15.2$ m/s

a) What is the maximum height above the ground?

$y'(t)= v_{initial} - gt =0 \rightarrow t= \frac{15.2}{9.8} \approx 1.55 s$

$y(1.55)=40+v_{initial} (1.55) -\frac{1}{2} g (1.55)^2 = 40+ 15.2(1.55) - .5 (9.8) (1.55)^2 \approx 51.8$ m

b) What is its speed 25 m below the rooftop?

$y(t)=40+v_{initial} t-\frac{1}{2} g t^2 $

$40-25=15=40+ 15.2 t- .5 (9.8) t^2 \rightarrow t \approx 4.3 $s

$y'(t)= v_{initial} - gt$

$y'(t)= 15.2 - (9.8)  (4.3) \approx - 26.9 $ m/s